# Escaping special characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, escaping, apostrophe

Firstly I know that I should be using stored procedures by now and am getting around to it, but I need a quick fix for one of my internal only apps.

Theres a form where we can enter some text, which is appended to a HTML email, formatted all nice and then sent off to joe customer before being recorded in the mysql DB.

The problem is that whenever a user uses an apostrophe ('), the recording to the db bit fails.

I tried to get around it by having an escaping function which simply replaced ' with /' but still my mysql errors persist.

My escape function was as so..

```vb
Public Function escapechars(ByVal input As String) As String

    input = input.Replace("\", "\\")
    input = input.Replace("%", "\%")
    input = input.Replace("'", "\'")
    input = input.Replace("", " \_")

    Return input

End Function
```

My function for saving to the db is like so...
(Bear in mind i was doing 'escapechars' prior to building db_newvalues)

```vb
 Public Function writesql(ByVal db_table As String, ByVal db_columns As String, ByVal db_newvalues As String)
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Try
        Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
        cn.Close()
        Dim timestamp As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim SQL As String
        cn.ConnectionString = orca_connection_string
        myCommand.Connection = cn
        cn.Open()
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        SQL = ("INSERT INTO " & db_table & "(" & db_columns & ") VALUES (" & db_newvalues & "); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        Dim newentryid As Integer = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        cn.Close()
        Return newentryid
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorHandling(ex.ToString)
        Return "Error"
    End Try

End Function
```

Any help appriciated! thanks in advance!

Comment: Use parameters and do not try to sanitize yourself user inputs.

Comment: @Steve, Especially when one doesn't know how to properly sanitize or how to do the one thing it is to prevent. Hint: SQL doesn't care or know what the intention of  `input.Replace("'", "\'")` was. In the amount of time spent attempting to bandaid the issue, the actual issue could have been resolved with SQL Parameters.

Comment: @TyCobb Exactly, to be honest though the problem here is made worse by the attempt to have a do_it_all method that dinamically tries to create the sql command. Another thing to avoid at all costs.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to escape the underscore, the % and the backslash, and the single quote is 'escaped' doubling it. IE ''

Comment: I lost interest at `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a string literal in a MySQL statement, the backslash character and the single quote character can be escaped by preceding with a backslash character. For example:

```
 SELECT 'here\'s a \\ backslash'
```

If single quotes are used to enclose a string literal, then a single quote within the literal can be encoded as two single quotes. For example.

```
 SELECT 'it''s fine like this too'
```

MySQL extends the ANSI SQL standard and allows double quotes to be used to enclose string literals, as long as sql_mode is not set to include ANSI_QUOTES. If we are enclosing string literals in double quotes, then double quotes within the literal will need to be escaped.

---

In a SQL string literal, there's no need to escape the underscore or percent characters. (It's only within the context of a LIKE comparison that the % and _ characters are wildcards; we only need to escape those if we are looking to do a match to those characters, to "escape" the character from being recognized as a wildcard.)

For debugging issues with dynamically generated this, consider logging the contents of the SQL string, and then test that SQL in another client.

---

NOTE: The `writesql` function appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Preventing SQL Injection will need to be the responsibility of every function that calls `writesql`.

The preferred pattern for mitigating SQL Injection vulnerabilities is to use *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*. (In VB.NET, that would be a Command object with parameters.)

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: looking at the guide here... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html can someone explain why in the vb.net example, we seem to be defining parameters twice. 

Can someone help me understand this more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726980/how-to-create-mysqlcommand-object-without-know-the-number-of-parameter  I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. The @parameter in the SQL text is a *placeholder*. Essentially just a symbol, it doesn't really matter what it's named, but appropriately descriptive names can be more helpful to the future reader vs `...,@b7,@b8,...`.   The `AddWithValue` supplies an actual value for the placeholder, and automatically takes care of any escaping that may be necessary. With server side prepares, the values aren't passed as part of the SQL text.)

Comment: In that vb.net example, the initial assignment of values (`Parameter.AddWithValues`) is adding a *parameter*, linking the line of code to the placeholder defined in the SQL text. In the vb.net example, the values assigned by the "WithValues" aren't being sent to the database, because there isn't a call to `ExecuteNonQuery` before the loop. If we had an `ExecuteNonQuery` before the loop, then we could do a `For i = 2 To 1000` loop, the difference there would be we would have row `(1,'one')` vs a row `(1,'a string value') as in the example.

Comment: From the code in the question, looks like its doing just a singleton insert, so just do the `AddWithValues`, supply the values you want to use, and call `ExecuteNonQuery`. (You don't need to execute more than one prepared statement. If you did need to execute the exact same statement, just with different values, use the pattern inside the loop in the example. Just `Parameters()`, because the Parameter was already added. We aren't adding another paramter, just assigning a value to parameter that was already added.